# Can't reach localhost using XAMPP (typo3)

Tags: apache, xampp, typo3

I tried to setup my typo3 page with XAMPP/apache.
I created my typo3 login and a phpMyAdmin user.
When I tried to log into my typo3 backend, it said that it couldn't reach the website. And that's still my problem, I just get an error screen which says **"Couldn't reach website", "connection refused".** (Not 1:1, my english isn't that sick.)

I already tried to change my ports (didn't work) and wrote localhost as ServerName into the xampp\apache\conf\extra file.

These are my errors in the error log file:

```
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.408550 2019] [core:warn] [pid 6408:tid 588] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.431396 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 588] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.431396 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 588] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug 11 2019 12:20:04
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.431396 2019] [core:notice] [pid 6408:tid 588] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.434746 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 588] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2792
[Wed Sep 04 14:33:59.900053 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2792:tid 696] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Hope you can help me, I am really desperate.

Comment: If you're using a windows system, I have created proper configuration for apache [here](https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f) Hope this will help you!

Comment: OMG thank you so much I love you, no idea how you did that but it worked perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I have added an answer. So, you can close the question

Comment: may sound stupid, but how do I close it? I accepted your answer and liked it, is there anything different that I can do?

Comment: You did it! With these people get a better idea whether you got the solution or not. In added, this will help in the future too.

Comment: perfect, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for windows, create proper Apache server configuration

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f.js" />
```

Restart server, That's it!